# What is the equivalent of "Latest value" and "Time range value" when creating a Cloudwatch dashboard using the JSON structure

Tags: amazon-cloudwatch, amazon-cloudwatch-metrics

Given this cloudwatch dashboard json fragment:

```
{
  "type": "metric",
  "x": 3,
  "y": 0,
  "width": 3,
  "height": 3,
  "properties": {
    "metrics": [
      [
        "AWS/ApiGateway",
        "Count",
        "ApiName",
        "my-api",
        {
          "stat": "Sum"
        }
      ]
    ],
    "view": "singleValue",
    "region": "eu-west-1",
    "period": 300,
    "title": "Number of api calls"
  }
}
```

The widget defaults to showing the "Latest value".  I want to see the "Time range value", as per the screenshot below.  How do I specify that setting using the cloudwatch dashboard json?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to the `properties` object:

```
"setPeriodToTimeRange": true
```

In your example:

```
{
  "type": "metric",
  "x": 3,
  "y": 0,
  "width": 3,
  "height": 3,
  "properties": {
    "metrics": [
      [
        "AWS/ApiGateway",
        "Count",
        "ApiName",
        "my-api",
        {
          "stat": "Sum"
        }
      ]
    ],
    "view": "singleValue",
    "region": "eu-west-1",
    "period": 300,
    "title": "Number of api calls",
    "setPeriodToTimeRange": true
  }
}
```

Comment: When I do that I get this error:   {
    "DashboardValidationMessages": [
        {
            "DataPath": "/widgets/1/properties",
            "Message": "The \"setPeriodToTimeRange\" property is not expected to be part of a widget definition, will be ignored"
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Interesting. Was the response 200? Can you check the dashboard itself? Was the property applied?

Comment: The property was not applied.  It also does not appear in the docs.  It only appears when you go the "graph source" tab of the console.

Comment: Actually you are right @Tartaglia, it does work.  I'm not sure what I did yesterday to make me believe otherwise.  Thx.